# How to debug Guice implicit bindings processor?

Tags: debugging, gwt, binding, guice

I've got a GWT application which uses Guice for injection.

The GinModule alone is huge (>100 different singleton bindings), and there's plenty of injection used everywhere.

When I try to compile the code now, I get a bindings processor exception:

```
[INFO]             [ERROR] Generator 'com.google.gwt.inject.rebind.GinjectorGenerator' threw an exception while rebinding 'de.timetoact.connections.adminui.client.application.AdminUI'
[INFO] java.lang.NullPointerException
[INFO]  at com.google.gwt.inject.rebind.BindingsProcessor.createImplicitBinding(BindingsProcessor.java:498)
[INFO]  at com.google.gwt.inject.rebind.BindingsProcessor.createImplicitBindingForUnresolved(BindingsProcessor.java:290)
[INFO]  at com.google.gwt.inject.rebind.BindingsProcessor.createImplicitBindingsForUnresolved(BindingsProcessor.java:278)
[INFO]  at com.google.gwt.inject.rebind.BindingsProcessor.process(BindingsProcessor.java:240)
```

**My Problem:** Guice doesn't tell me for which key an implicit binding can't be created (so that I could have at least an idea of where to look in the source code).

I have already set the GWT compiler to TRACE level, however all console entries above the exception refer to the creation of previous implicit bindings. Besides that, having a look at the BindingsProcessor code shows that there are no places where a log entry would be written before the exception happens.

**Versions:** I am using Guice 3.0 and GWT 2.7

**Question:** How can I figure out where the issue is? Would an upgrade to Guice 4.0 help? Are there some other tracing options I could activate? Debugging code to put into my GinModule?

Comment: How about running the GWT compiler with a debugger, setting a breakpoint where the exception is thrown to try to gather more context?

Comment: or if you are using Eclipse set a exception breakpoint on a NullPointerException